# How can I dismiss an iOS Swift SKOverlay?

Tags: ios, swift

I read about how to create an SKOverlay to cross promote an app here: https://sarunw.com/posts/cross-promote-apps-with-skoverlay/

But the view seems to stay visible when after a segue to another view controller.

So I would like to dismiss the SKOverlay promotional banner when the view that is displaying it disappears.

Answer (score 3):

They way to do this is to call a function like this in viewWillDisappear:

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
  private func dismissOverlay() {
    guard let scene = view.window?.windowScene else {
      return
    }
    SKOverlay.dismiss(in: scene)
  }
```